# What does Trundle's Ice Pillar block?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know Trundle's Ice Pillar counts as impassable terrain, but what skills does he block?
I know about Shyvana's dragonform being blocked (happened to me yesterday) and I got intrigued.

Answer (score 2):

Trundle's ice pillar counts as impassible ground as long as it lasts, so any movement abilities that would otherwise wind up inside the pillar will be shunted to either the far side or the near side (whichever is shorter). This means especially short movement abilities (such as Lucian's Relentless Pursuit, or Nidalee's Pounce) may not be able to "jump" the pillar at all.

(I would imagine that Shyvana's Dragonform should be able to cross the pillar, at least if she starts adjacent to it.)

Skill shots, including things like Blitzcrank's Rocket Grab, will simply pass through the pillar, just like casting a skill shot through any other impassible terrain (like jungle walls).

Comment: I think you can compare it with any wall-like terrain from a map. When you are standing behind a wall, you can Rocket Grab through it, you can flash over it, but you can't walk through it. With the extra addition that 'jumping' skills (note the difference between jumping and blinking) are blocked as well.

Comment: @Joetjah Well, jumping skills aren't blocked per se, but if you don't have enough distance, the ability just won't take you over it. (Same as if you'd tried to jump into impassible terrain elsewhere on the map)

Comment: I'm wondering since Shyvana's dragonform supposely gets blocked. It's a pretty large jump there. How about pantheon trying to blockjump on Trundle with the pillar in between them?

Comment: @Joetjah I wouldn't consider Dragonform a particularly large jump, but it should work if you start adjacent to the pillar. As for Pantheon, his W wouldn't be affected, since it's targeted. If the ability activates and he jumps at trundle, he's going to jump next to trundle, period.

Comment: Doesn't dragonform have a larger range than, say, Shen's taunt? I'd consider that large and if neither of them goes through the pillar, I could state that 'sliding/jumping' skills don't get through the pillar..

Comment: I wonder what happens if a Blitzcrank is standing at the pillar and grabs an enemy to the place where the pillar is... So much scenario's to test!

Comment: @Joetjah The enemy will be pulled adjacent to Blitzcrank. The pillar behaves just like any other terrain; there are gaps that Shen / Shyvana can and can't dash over. The pillar is no exception.

Comment: as far as i know temporary terrain can't block a jump, as long as the jump distance is large enough and the player is positioned correctly before attempting to jump the pillar, they should be able to pass through it. there was a short time that anivia's wall was blocking all jumps but that was a bug that riot fixed.

Comment: @Ravekner Right. Only abilities that would leave the user inside the pillar (since it's impassible) get shortened.

Comment: If a blink or jump would land you in impassable terrain, or if you create a ward or pet in impassable terrain, the game will instead place you (or the object) to the nearest passable terrain instead. So in order to clear intermediate terrain with a jump or blink ability, you only need to get more than half way through the obstacle. Theoretically, this bit of game mechanic would allow you to nearly double the range of blinks, jumps, wards etc. under the right circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Situation: Red leesin is jumping at blue Anivia.

Trundle from **either team could cast pillar to stop leesin as long as the animation for leesin has already begun**, however if trundle casts pillar too early, leesin would skip right pass it.

Same case for Anivia, she can only stop leesin if she casts wall after leesin starts the animation for his dash.

This applys for all walls and dashes(Including Tristana's jump, Vayne's tumble and Quinn's vault).

Answer (score 0):

**Almost nothing, besides movement.**

It doesn't block projectiles. They go through impassable terrain the same way they go through walls.

It doesn't block jumping abilities either. However, it will move the landing point if it was precisely where the pillar now is: in most cases, the jump will be shorter.

Impassable terrain created by an ability does **not** count as a wall for the purpose of abilities like Nautilus' hook (Q) or Poppy's charge (E).

Answer (score 0):

**It's the same as an Anivia wall, in a sense that it can block only movement**

Trundle pillar is just like a condensed minion pillar. You can "jump" over it, like with a jax jump for instance. Your dragonform would be blocked, if your landing place would be on the pillar, and the game does not allow you to land in terrain.